# trying to update document country if country exists then need to add state and then city in node and mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```js
exports.addstate = async (req, res, next) => {

  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var dbo = db.db(DATEBASE);
      const {country,name,state_code} = req.body;
      var query = [{$match: {iso2: country}}];
      var newvalues = { name: name,state_code: state_code} ;
      dbo.collection("countries").updateOne(query, newvalues, {upsert: true}, function(err, doc) {
          if (err) return res.send(500, {error: err});
          return res.send('Succesfully saved.');
      });
    });
}
```

I have a country list in the database now I am trying to add fields if the country is present.

countrt --state[array,{city[]}]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

might be you need to try with this

```
exports.addstate = async (req, res, next) => {

  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var dbo = db.db(DATEBASE);
      const {country,name,state_code} = req.body;
      var query = {iso2: country}
      var newvalues =  { $push: { name: name,state_code: state_code} } ;
      dbo.collection("countries").updateOne(query,{"$states":newvalues}, {new: true}, function(err, doc) {
          if (err) return res.send(500, {error: err});
          return res.send('Succesfully saved.');
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: I want to pass this as query ,let query = [{$match: {iso2: country}}]; can't we pass this as query ?? I tried and it says query should be plain object  and  I need to access particular object with in an array in db

Comment: please try with an updated answer(I updated).

Comment: I have done already by using $set($push) and {upsert :true} its working and tq

Comment: ronak-sutariya@
name:India,
iso2:"IN:
States:[
name:"state_name",
state_code:"AP,
 city:[
    name:"city_name",
    city_code:"CN"
   ]
]

trying to project the city name by taking the iso2 and state_code can you help

Comment: @Krishna can you write query as proper readable format